# Difference between 'value' and 'number' in Dropwizard Metrics CachedGauges

Tags: prometheus, jmx, dropwizard, hikaricp, codahale-metrics

I'm using Dropwizard Metrics to expose the metrics of an HikariCP connection pool. These metrics are then piped to Prometheus using its *jmx_exporter*.

One of the exposed metrics is the number of active connections, which, [as stated on the HikariCP wiki](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Dropwizard-Metrics), one of the exposed metrics is the number of active connections in the pool, which is kept as a `CachedGauge`. When I read the metrics, I see both a `..._pool_activeconnections_value` and a `..._pool_activeconnections_number`.

According to what I could find on [Dropwizard Metrics' documentation](https://metrics.dropwizard.io/4.1.2/manual/core.html), a gauge only exposes a *value*. What is the other metric ?